# c# - Hacerle un add a una lista DataTable

Tags: c#

estoy realizando una funcion que recibe datos desde mi base de datos, y con otro metodo estoy recorriendo el dataset(que viene con los datos de bd)y los quieero agregar en una lista dataTable, mi problema esta en hacer el add, que no se como hacerlo correctamente, porque me tira error de todas las formas que he probado! 
paso mi codigo

muchas gracias!

```js
[HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult RecorroDS(string NombreSeccion, string NombreCategoria, string NombreEstilo, string NombreMarca, int NumTalle)
        {
            try
            {
                var datosCInterno = Metodos.MisMetodos.CargoDatosConInterno(Casa(), NombreSeccion, NombreCategoria, NombreEstilo, NombreMarca, NumTalle);
                List<DataTable> aux = new List<DataTable>();
                foreach (DataRow dr in datosCInterno.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    double fabricante = Convert.ToDouble(dr["PROVEEDOR"]);
                    string articulo = dr["COD_ART"].ToString();
                    string descripcion = dr["DESCR"].ToString();
                    string color = dr["color"].ToString();
                    double numero = Convert.ToDouble(dr["NRO"]);
                    var Imagen = RutaImagen(fabricante, articulo, descripcion, color, numero);
                    aux.Add();
                    //aca esta mi problema, no se como hacerle el add y
                    //que me agregue fabricante, art,desc,color, num e imagen
                }
                return Ok(datosCInterno);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) { Content = new StringContent(ex.Message) });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yo creo que Lista<DataTable> es una gran confunsion.. o sea.. vos queres guardar una lista que contiene Tablas????? para mi, querias guardar una lista de algun tipo de dato (que no me queda claro, porque cada fila contiene distintos datos)... Creo que tu problema viene por ahi, pero no tengo idea como ponerte una respuesta.. No tenes una clase que guarde tosdos esos datos????

Comment: Si ahi me confundi fuertemente

Comment: puedes ingresar al [chat] si queres que te ayudemos a organizar tu pregunta y tal vez obtener una respuesta que podamos poner aca

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo que puedes hacer es definir una variable de tipo `DataTable` para almacenar los datos y después llenar la lista así:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult RecorroDS(string NombreSeccion, string NombreCategoria, string NombreEstilo, string NombreMarca, int NumTalle)
  {
    try
     {
       var datosCInterno = Metodos.MisMetodos.CargoDatosConInterno(Casa(), NombreSeccion, NombreCategoria, NombreEstilo, NombreMarca, NumTalle);
        List<DataTable> aux = new List<DataTable>();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataRow dr in datosCInterno.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
          table.Columns.Add("fabricante ",Convert.ToDouble(dr["PROVEEDOR"]));
          table.Columns.Add("articulo",dr["COD_ART"].ToString());
          table.Columns.Add("descripcion",dr["DESCR"].ToString());
          table.Columns.Add("color",dr["color"].ToString());
          table.Columns.Add("numero",Convert.ToDouble(dr["NRO"]));
          table.Columns.Add("Imagen",RutaImagen(fabricante, articulo, descripcion, color, numero);

         aux.Add(table);

        }
         return Ok(aux);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
     {
       throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) { Content = new StringContent(ex.Message) });
     }
  }
```

O puedes probar los siguiente, Crea una clase así:

```
 public class claseDto
 {
        public double fabricante { get; set; }
        public string articulo { get; set; }
        public string descripcion { get; set; }
        public string color { get; set; }
        public double numero { get; set; }
        public RutaImagen Imagen { get; set; }
  }
```

Y después llamas he implementas la clase de esta forma

```
   [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult RecorroDS(string NombreSeccion, string NombreCategoria, string NombreEstilo, string NombreMarca, int NumTalle)
      {
        try
         {
           var datosCInterno = Metodos.MisMetodos.CargoDatosConInterno(Casa(), NombreSeccion, NombreCategoria, NombreEstilo, NombreMarca, NumTalle);
            List<DataTable> aux = new List<DataTable>();
            claseDto clase = new claseDto();
            foreach (DataRow dr in datosCInterno.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
              clase.fabricante = Convert.ToDouble(dr["PROVEEDOR"]);
              clase.articulo = dr["COD_ART"].ToString();
              clase.descripcion = dr["DESCR"].ToString();
              clase.color = dr["color"].ToString();
              clase.numero = Convert.ToDouble(dr["NRO"]);
              clase.Imagen = RutaImagen(fabricante, articulo, descripcion, color, numero);

             aux.Add(clase);

            }
             return Ok(aux);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
         {
           throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) { Content = new StringContent(ex.Message) });
         }
      }
```

Comment: donde dice List<DataTable> supongo que quisiste poner List<claseDto>?

Comment: Si , voy a editar mi respuesta

Comment: y el return deberia ser return Ok(aux), porque si no, no tengo ni idea que estas tratando de retornar (o porque retornas algo que recorriste y no hiciste nada).

Comment: Claro estaba retornando mal! Ahora por postman estoy verificando el metodo pero me da vacio, cambie el add por un aux.ImportRow(dr)  y me da vacio... antes con el add que tenia me daba " esta fila ya pertenece a otra tabla "

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO me temo que el código como está va a generar errores. El método Add de la colección Columns de la DataTable agrega una definición de columna (no un valor); es decir, modifica el esquema.
El código que compartes va a intentar agregar "n" veces la definición de las columnas a la DataTable (tantas como registros haya retornado la consulta).

Comment: @tato8vio Probaste el código de la respuesta ? que error te genera ?

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO si, me dice que no puedo convertir de double a system.Type, o int, o string..........
Ademas de que le tendria que asignar un nombre, porque lo necesito para RutaFoto que le paso esos nombres como parametro y me devuelve una url

Comment: no hay alguna forma de pasarte un screen

Comment: Esta respuesta estaba bien antes. Ahora esta mal.

Comment: @gbianchi ya la deje como estaba

Answer (score 0):

Si bien no recomiendo utilizar DataSets y DataTables, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Define una variable de tipo DataTable, no debe ser una List de
   DataTable: `DataTable aux = new DataTable();.`
2. Define la estructura que va a tener dicha DataTable, es decir, la lista de campos que la     van a componer (acá veo que sería un reflejo de la estructura que tiene `datosCInterno.Tables[0]`. Tendria que ser algo como lo siguiente:

   aux.Columns.Add("PROVEEDOR", typeof(String));
   aux.Columns.Add("COD_ART", typeof(String));
   aux.Columns.Add("DESCR", typeof(String));
3. Utilizando la variable definida previamente, invoca el método NewRow
   DataRow newRow = aux.NewRow()
4. Llenas los valores del nuevo registro.
5. Agregas el nuevo registro a la tabla. `aux.Add(newRow)`.

Sin embargo, me pregunto por qué no haces un simple `return OK(datosCInterno.Tables[0])` (a menos que estés haciendo algo más con la tabla de lo que no hayas puesto el código).

Comment: Esta calculando una ruta a la imagen (o eso parece) al hacer var Imagen = RutaImagen(fabricante, articulo, descripcion, color, numero);

Comment: Sí, de ahí la duda de si estaba haciendo algo más, porque la variable Imagen está definida dentro del scope del For y no se utiliza más adelante.

Answer (score 0):

Crea una nueva row de ese DataSet.
Una vez que ya lo tengas cargado.

```
 DataRow dr = datosCInterno .Tables[0].NewRow();
 dr["COD_ART"] = "Cod1";
 dr["DESCR"]= "Descripcion";
 dr["color"]="Azul";
```

Luego Inserta esta nueva row, en la datatable

```
datosCInterno .Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0); //0 es la posicion
```